# Why I can't deploy this ROOT.war file into my remote Tomcat server? When I restart Tomcat it creates an "empty" ROOT directory

Tags: java, tomcat, deployment, tomcat7

I have the following problem.

I am working on a **Java web application** and I am experiencing the following problem trying to deploy it on a remote **Tomcat** server (on a remote Linux machine).

So I take my **ROOT.war** file generated by maven compilation and I put into the **webapp** directory in my remote Tomcat server, this one: **/usr/local/tomcat/myproject/webapps**

where **myproject** should be a specific Tomcat instance because it contains:

```
[myuser@myserver myproject]$ ls
conf  lib  logs  server  shared  temp  webapps  work
```

So I do the following steps:

1) I stop Tomcat.

2) I enter into the **webapps** directory and here I remove the **ROOT** subdirectory.

3) I put my **ROOT.war**file into **/usr/local/tomcat/myproject/webapps/ROOT/** directory.

4) I start Tomcat.

Now I expect that at start time Tomcat unpack the **ROOT.war** file into a new **ROOT** directory so my application should be deployed.

The problem is that after the Tomcat restart I have the new **/usr/local/tomcat/myproject/webapps/ROOT/** directory but it doesn't contain my deployed application. This folder is almost empty, infact it contains only:

```
[myuser@myserver ROOT]$ ls -R
.:
WEB-INF

./WEB-INF:
classes

./WEB-INF/classes:
reports

./WEB-INF/classes/reports:
```

As you can see it only contains the **WEB-INF** directory withs some basic subfolder.

Why? What am I missing? Can I manually unpack my **ROOT.war** file in some way or is it not a good solution? How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using Maven to build projects?If you use Maven to build a project, you can use the following configuration

```
 <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>tomcat7-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <port>8080</port>
                    <path>/</path>
                    <url>http://192.168.25.135:8080/manager/text</url>
                    <username>tomcat</username>
                    <password>tomcat</password>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Configuration file in Tomcat:

```
<tomcat-users>
    <role rolename="admin-gui"/>
    <role rolename="admin-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-gui"/>
    <role rolename="manager-script"/>
    <role rolename="manager-jmx"/>
    <role rolename="manager-status"/>
    <user username="tomcat" password="tomcat" roles="manager-gui,manager-script,manager-jmx,manager-status,admin-script,admin-gui"/>
</tomcat-users>
```

Use the Maven command:

```
mvn tomcat7:redeploy
```

Comment: yes I use Tomcat do build but then I will use Jenkins to deploy (this is only a first manual step). What exactly does this configuration?